# Groovy throws Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String) error while parsing LinkedHashMap

Tags: groovy

I'm trying to check if the key is present in the kafka output message, if so do further operations.
Output message from the kafka topic is below

```
["random_name_547hcg": {
    "access_Data": {
        "name": "BU",
        "repo": "CRX",
        "Id": "908hngt"
    },
    "level": "easy",
    "check_status": {
        "prod": 0,
        "dev": 3,
        "QA": 2,
        "UAT": 1
    },
    "Test_Result": {
        "results": [
            {
                "id": "a20e025e0451eeed05d94a4cfc4523e58a",
                "name": "ImageVerify",
                "Release": "3.0",
                "wrapper": [
                    "All"
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    "output": "failure"
}]
```

Data type of the output message is `java.util.LinkedHashMap`

My code snippet

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import kafkarelatedpackage

key = 'random_name_547hcg'

def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper()
def kafConsumer = new ConsumerClassKafka(servers, topic)
def kafmsg = kafConsumer.getMessages()
messg = slurper.parseText(kafmsg)

if (messg.containsKey(key)) {
 println "Yes"
 } else {
 println "No"
}
```

but it throws

```
Possible solutions: parseText(java.lang.String), parse(java.io.File), parse(java.io.Reader), parse(java.net.URL)
```

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: the `kafConsumer.getMessages()` is obviously NOT a string.

Comment: Your edit made it worse to grasp, what is actually happening there.  From your previous version my guess would be, that this is the toString from a map from String key to String (where the value is JSON encoded). So my _guess_ is, that you are already getting a map from your Kafka consumer and you have to actually slurp the value from that map.

Comment: @cfrick : Yes, i'm getting a map from my Kafka consumer. I verified that by assigning the kafka output to a variable and determining the datatype using`.getClass()` and it gives `java.util.LinkedHashMap`

Comment: and trying to slurp the key - `random_name_547hcg` from it

Answer (score 1):

The output you are showing is either

- "serialized" using `.toString()`; yet the shown text in the question
  has been altered (`.toString()` will not add quotes around keys and
  `.inspect()` would have added single quotes
- already de-serialized from your Kafka-tooling to a map (but then
  printed for debugging and manipulated for the question, see the point
  above)

For the later you just have to swap things around a bit.  You want to
JSON-de-serialize the *value* of the `random_name_547hcg` key: `def msg = slurper.parseText(kafmsg.get('random_name_547hcg))`.

For the former part: groovy `.toString()` is unsuitable to serialize
data and must not be used. Fix the producer.  Use JSON or whatever you
see fit.